# do not reset localstorage on page change

Tags: javascript, i18next

I have this code that is inserted at the bottom of every page:

```
async function i18Loader() {
  const langs = [<?php echo $mylang; ?>];
  const jsons = await Promise.all(
    langs.map((l) => fetch("lang/" + l + ".json").then((r) => r.json()))
  );
  const res = langs.reduce((acc, l, idx) => {
    acc[l] = { translation: jsons[idx] };
    return acc;
  }, {});

  await i18next

    .init({
      lng: localStorage.getItem("lan") || 'it',
      debug: true,
      resources: res,
      fallbackLng: "it-IT",
      backend: {
        backendOptions: [{
          store: typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window.localStorage : null
        }, {
          loadPath: 'lang/{{lng}}.json' // xhr load path for my own fallback
        }]
      }
    });

  function updateContent() {
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("i18nelement");
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      const element = elements[i];
      const k = element.getAttribute("data-i18n");
      element.innerHTML = i18next.t(k);
    }
  }

  updateContent();
  i18next.on("languageChanged", () => {
    updateContent();
  });

  const langSelector = document.getElementById("langSelector");
  langSelector.removeAttribute("disabled");
  langSelector.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    i18next.changeLanguage(e.target.value);
    localStorage.setItem("lan", e.target.value);

  });

}

i18Loader();
```

it keeps the language if I don't change the page, but if I go to another page it sets the localstorage item again and "empties" the localstorage, how can I avoid this? help me Thanks